# How do I disable an entire example based on features?

Tags: rust

My Rust project has **examples** that are only relevant to certain **features**.

I can ignore the main function with:

```
#[cfg(feature = "foo")]
fn main() {
```

But other statements that depend on the feature cause errors when I run `cargo test`. So I have to use a number of cfg attribute statements on functions and use statements to disable code that depends on the feature.

Is there a way to just ignore an entire example file based on the feature configuration?

Also, because main is hidden without the feature, `cargo test` has this error:

> error: main function not found

So this isn't a good solution.

Comment: Not sure, therefore no answer, but what about `#![cfg(feature = "foo")]` on top of your file? This refers to the module/crate then.

Comment: Doesn't work because the example isn't a module. If I put it at the top, it just disables the first statement, which is *extern crate*, causing missing crate errors.

Comment: So you can wrap all of your code in a module and *use mymodule::\** in main, but then you need to *pub use* any use statement within the module and add pub to every function used by main. So that's even more setup to achieve this.

Comment: @Arlo if it “just disables the first statement” you have written `#[cfg(feature = "foo")]` not `#![cfg(feature = "foo")]`.

Comment: I wonder if putting the whole file iinto other file and using  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include!.html with `#![cfg(feature = "foo")] ` would do.

Answer (score 5):

Make more specific use of the `#[cfg]` directive, providing both a `main()` when `foo` is enabled, and a `main()` when `foo` is not:

```
extern crate blah;
// other code which will still compile even without "foo" feature

#[cfg(feature = "foo")]
fn main() {
    use blah::OnlyExistsWithFoo;
    // code which requires "foo" feature
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "foo"))]
fn main() {
    // empty main function for when "foo" is disabled
}
```